# Stretch multiple child containers vertically with same space using Flexbox, by handling dynamic addition of child containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent container with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row`. The child containers are stretching horizontally fine. The problem is that the child containers can increase dynamically and they all need to contain perfectly in the Parent container, as shown in the below images:

## First case

[image]

## Second case

[image]

In the above two images, I am handling the situation by manually setting the all child containers height as `50%` and `33.33%` respectively (*whenever the child containers are increasing dynamically*). Instead of doing so, I want the flexbox to handle it and hoping this is possible.

Here is the code:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Mr_Green/pen/KJamjw) (*Remove the last three child containers and set the `.child` height to `50%` to check the first case*)

Comment: I tried this... but not get any solution.. i found this  : all div show in single line.. then all div get auto  height.

Comment: Is this either possible with `display: grid`?

Comment: Yes Possible in grid, but grid will not allow "second row" box same height as above row boxs.

Comment: Thanks, I want them to be of same height.

Comment: Yes i have solution

Comment: check my answer...

Answer (score 0):

The element that contain the big amount of text is creating the issue as you have noticed since it will have the bigger height. On idea to overcome this is to make its content out of the flow thus technically all the element will be empty and will then take the same amount of space.

Check the below example where I put the first and the second case:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
}

.child{
 /* height: 33.33%;*/
}

.one{
  background-color: red;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.two{
  background-color: green;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.three{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.four{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 50%;
  position:relative;
}

.five{
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
}

.four-wrapper{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child one">
  </div>
  <div class="child two">
  </div>
  <div class="child three">
  </div>
  <div class="child four">
    <div class="four-wrapper">
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child five"></div>

<div class="child one">
  </div>
  <div class="child two">
  </div>
  <div class="child three">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child one">
  </div>
  <div class="child two">
  </div>
  <div class="child three">
  </div>
  <div class="child four">
    <div class="four-wrapper">
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child five"></div>

</div>
```

To make this generic, you can make all the content out of the flow inside all the elements:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 400px;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 20px;
}

.child{
 /* height: 33.33%;*/
 position:relative;
}
.child>* {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  overflow:auto;
}

.one{
  background-color: red;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.two{
  background-color: green;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.three{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.four{
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  width: 50%;
}

.five{
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
}

.four-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child one">
  </div>
  <div class="child two">
    <div>
         a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child three">
  <div>
      b<br>b<br>bbb<br>b<br>bbb<br>b<br>bbb<br>b<br>bbb<br>b<br>bbb<br>b<br>bbb<br>b<br>bbb<br>b<br>bbb<br>b<br>bbb<br>b<br>bbb<br>b<br>bbb<br>b<br>bbb<br>b<br>bbb
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child four">
    <div class="four-wrapper">
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      a
      <br>
      a a
      <br>
      a a
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child five"></div>

<div class="child one">
  </div>
  <div class="child two">
  </div>
  <div class="child three">
  </div>
</div>
```